# Smtp send email with style sheet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp, mailmessage

I want to include style sheet in the email body while sending an email with SMTP.
Is it possible, as I don't want to give inline style to each and every html tag.

If i include `class="sampleClass"` in any HTML tag then it is not appearing in the email view source, why?

How can I include internal style sheet in body, while sending email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As this page says: http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/ you cannot link to an external style sheet, but you can add inline styles. so it looks like adding inline styles is a viable option.

Also, you cannot add styles to the head section, since some mail clients do not support it, again refer to http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/, so just concentrate on adding inline styles.

Comment: but can we have internal style

Comment: not all mail clients will support it, also read the edited answer again

Answer (score 1):

You can use style tag and define there inside mail itself. As follow

```
 <style type="text/css">
 </style>
```

and use those styles in you message.

similar question

1. [How to send web page in email body with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584170/how-to-send-web-page-in-email-body-with-css)
2. [CSS on Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690189/css-on-email)

Comment: but I cant find class attributes inside email body, while looking for its viewsource

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible as such, having a consistent and working template in major webmails and mail client is already very tricky, and using styles, even in an inline `<style>` tag make it even more tricky. Actually, to design a mail template, you should forget everything you know about best practices on the web, and consider this a completely different medium that appears to understand some HTML and CSS.