# How to simply create a decorated a confirmation email in ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So I have an email confirmation system that sends emails to new users in order for them to confirm their emails. The current email looks like this:
[image]

I want it to look like this:
[image]

**But there is a problem,** the line that sends the emails takes 3 arguments, `email address,` header`&`HTML content`. The current content is only one line long so it is not that bad to write it inside the function.
But, the second style is more than 100 lines long, and with CSS styling. I have managed to compress it into only a line of code but it looks terrible (in the code and in email itself)
How the email looks like now:
[image]

Code (NEW):

```
var Code = $"<html><head><meta charset='utf - 8'><meta http-equiv='x - ua - compatible' content='ie = edge'><title>Email Confirmation</title><meta name='viewport' content='width = device - width, initial - scale = 1'><style type='text / css'>@media screen {{@font - face {{font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;src: local('Source Sans Pro Regular'), local('SourceSansPro-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v10/ODelI1aHBYDBqgeIAH2zlBM0YzuT7MdOe03otPbuUS0.woff) format('woff');}}@font-face {{font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;src: local('Source Sans Pro Bold'), local('SourceSansPro-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v10/toadOcfmlt9b38dHJxOBGFkQc6VGVFSmCnC_l7QZG60.woff) format('woff');}}body,table,td,a {{-ms - text - size - adjust: 100%; /* 1 */-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */}}table,td {{mso - table - rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;}}img {{-ms - interpolation - mode: bicubic;}}a[x-apple-data-detectors] {{font - family: inherit !important;font-size: inherit !important;font-weight: inherit !important;line-height: inherit !important;color: inherit !important;text-decoration: none !important;}}div[style*='margin: 16px 0; '] {{margin: 0 !important;}}body {{width: 100% !important;height: 100% !important;padding: 0 !important;margin: 0 !important;}}table {{border - collapse: collapse !important;}}a {{color: #1a82e2;}}img {{height: auto;line-height: 100%;text-decoration: none;border: 0;outline: none;}}</style></head><body style='background - color: #e9ecef;'><div class='preheader' style='display: none; max-width: 0; max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; color: #fff; opacity: 0;'>Congratulations on joining SvivaTeam! Please confirm your email to start helping the environment.</div><table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'><tr><td align='center' bgcolor='#e9ecef'><table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='max-width: 600px;'><tr><td align='left' valign='top' style='padding: 36px 24px;'></td></tr></table></td></t><tr><td align='center' bgcolor='#e9ecef'><table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='max-width: 600px;'><tr><td align='center' bgcolor='#ffffff' style='padding: 36px 24px 0; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; border-top: 3px solid #d4dadf;'><h1 style='margin: 0; font-size: 32px; font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 48px;'>Welcome to SvivaTeam!</h1></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td align='center' bgcolor='#e9ecef'><table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='max-width: 600px;'><tr><td align='left' bgcolor='#ffffff' style='padding: 24px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;'><p style='margin: 0;'>Hello user we are glad that you decided to join our great community!</p><p>Last thing before you can start reporting environmental issues we need you to confirm your email address by pressing the button below.</p><p style = 'margin: 0;'>If you didn't create an account with <a href='https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png'>SvivaTeam</a>, please ignore this email.</p></td></tr><tr><td align='left' bgcolor='#ffffff'><table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'> <tr><td align='center' bgcolor='#ffffff' style='padding: 12px;'><table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td align='center' bgcolor='#1a82e2' style='border-radius: 6px;'><a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}' target='_blank' style='display: inline-block; padding: 16px 36px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 6px;'>START REPORTING</a></td></tr>                    </table>                  </td>                </tr>              </table>            </td>          </tr>          <tr>            <td align='left' bgcolor='#ffffff' style='padding: 24px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;'>              <p style='margin: 0;'>If the button doesn't work, copy and paste the following link in your browser:</p>              <p style='margin: 0;'><a href='https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png' target='_blank'>placeholder</a></p>            </td>          </tr>          <tr>            <td align='left' bgcolor='#ffffff' style='padding: 24px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; border-bottom: 3px solid #d4dadf'>              <p style='margin: 0;'>Thanks for joining us,<br> SvivaTeam</p>            </td>          </tr>        </table>      </td>    </tr>    <tr>      <td align='center' bgcolor='#e9ecef' style='padding: 24px;'>        <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='max-width: 600px;'>          <tr>            <td align='center' bgcolor='#e9ecef' style='padding: 12px 24px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #666;'>              <p style='margin: 0;'>You received this email because we received a request for creating a new account. If you didn't request creating an account you can safely delete this email.</p>            </td>          </tr>        </table>      </td>    </tr>  </table></body></html>";

await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email", Code); //Change the message
```

**I can't** use a file to store the HTML because the main button's action is a `C#` code.

THE CODE: `HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)`

It is really messed up and I want it to look good in the code and look good in the email.

Comment: Why can't you store the email template in a file or database? It doesn't look like the button's action being C# code would restrict that.

Comment: this is where [transactional emails](https://postmarkapp.com/blog/what-is-transactional-email-and-how-is-it-used) come into play, and there are services out there that make it really nice... you are experiencing the hurdles of creating email templates, and each browser and each email application treats them differently, you should use inline CSS and `<table>` for design for example, here's a [nice repo for you to start](https://github.com/leemunroe/responsive-html-email-template) (1/2)

Comment: regarding the button action, you normally send them back to your application with an id, for example `mydomain.com/start-reporting/vyv64dNY6WAz5nuzXWVg` and that id will match the email address you sent so you can connect that action to a client in your application... and you continue from that endpoint in your own application (2/2)

Comment: @Orion let's first go with your idea. Do you think that I would save the code a `.cshtml` and load it will work? and if so, how can I move the C# code from the function to another file

Comment: Also @balexandre, If I use the template you have provided how Do I add the confirmation link to it? I have no experience doing it yet nor the knowledge of how to.

Comment: I figured out that my problem is that the CSS does not work. I just need to know how to make it work.

Comment: Hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690189/css-on-email) can help you to make css work.

Comment: Thank you, everybody, I have found that the style @balexandre has provided works fine.